# Directing to a named port on Digital ocean

Tags: nginx, ip, port

So assuming I have:

1) IP address: 10:11:12:13

2) An active port: 5678

I can access my app on: http://10:11:12:13:5678

3) I have a domain name: domainName.com

I can access my app on: www.domainName.com:5678

How can I access the App on something like:

www.domainName.com/appName ?

I use nginx.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing with the browser, you enter the server through the port 80 in http case, and port 443 in https case. You can make a file in sites-avaliable on /etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/yourfile , and put this server bracket:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourServerName.com www.yourServerName.com;
    #bracket that will be used when accessing though this 2 server names.
    access_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.com-error.log;
    #logs are love logs are life
    location /appName {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;          
      proxy_pass http://www.domainName.com:5678;

    }

    location / {
      #anything else you want to redirct on this domain?
    }
}
```

Then symlink from sites-enabled to this file:

```
    ln -ls ../sites-avaliable/yourfile . 


    sudo nginx -t


    sudo service nginx reload
```

Something like that should work for http, https it's almost the same but with certificates. Tell my if you have any doubts.

Comment: Hi flaixman, I followed the steps above but I still can't access the app at: www.domainName.com/appName. Here is the line in error.log: 2019/01/09 22:20:22 [error] 10833#10833: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 222.333.44.55, server: domainName.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "www. domainName.com", referrer: "http://www.domainName.com/appName”.

Comment: Here is the respective line of the access.log: 222.333.44.55 - - [09/Jan/2019:22:20:22 +0000] "GET /appName HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"